# Double range query in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cql

I would like to perform a double range query for getting latitude and longitude points near one point,

in Cassandra it seems possible now, I just tried

```
create column family users
 with comparator=UTF8Type
 AND key_validation_class=UTF8Type
 and column_metadata=[{column_name: full_name, validation_class: UTF8Type},
 {column_name: type, validation_class: UTF8Type, index_type: KEYS},
 {column_name: lat, validation_class: LongType, index_type: KEYS},
 {column_name: lon, validation_class:  LongType, index_type: KEYS}];

SET users['a']['type']='test';                                             
SET users['b']['type']='test';
SET users['c']['type']='test';
SET users['a']['lat']='12';                                                
SET users['b']['lat']='9'; 
SET users['c']['lat']='12';
SET users['b']['lon']='1'; 
SET users['a']['lon']='4';
SET users['c']['lon']='2';
get users where type = 'test' and lon < '6' and lon > '3' and lat > '10' and lat < '13';
```

RowKey: a
=> (column=lat, value=12, timestamp=1336339056413000)
=> (column=lon, value=4, timestamp=1336339088170000)
=> (column=type, value=test, timestamp=1336339033765000)

1 Row Returned.

But I'm quite worried about performances when adding thousands of points, If those 3 columns are indexed.

1) I had to use the 'type' column indexed, because without it, the query fails

```
No indexed columns present in index clause with operator EQ
```

is it possible to bypass it?

2) It could be interesting to naturally sort all the data by lat or lon, and then just query on the other one,

So just doing a SliceQuery for the lat between x and y  followed by a query

```
get users where type = 'test' and lon < '6' and lon > '3';
```

To order the CF not by rows names but by another field (ex: a String lat+lon and a UTF8 comparator) how can this be done?

thanks

Comment: To clear up what may be an important initial misunderstanding: none of this is CQL. You're using the special syntax of the cassandra-cli tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes like vladaman said, for Cassandra geocells is the (only?) good way, in [Python](http://code.google.com/p/geomodel/source/browse/trunk/geo/geocell.py) or in [Java](http://code.google.com/p/javageomodel/source/browse/trunk/geocell/src/test/java/com/beoui/utils/HowToUseGeocell.java)

Answer (score 1):

Your solution may work on smaller dataset. Once it grows you need some Spatial index to perform fast lookups. Cassandra does not support spatial indexes as for now. I would suggest you look at **GeoCell / GeoHash**

You create hash for each Point coordinate and then you can perform range queries over the string. In this case Cassandra Range Queries would be a good option.

> **GeoHash** is a hierarchical spatial data structure which subdivides space into buckets of grid shape.

**Links:**

- [geohashing](/questions/tagged/geohashing)
- Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash
- Java Implementation http://code.google.com/p/javageomodel/